Parts similar to 2x4 hinge plate
I can't find a similar Lego piece. It should be like in the photo, only solid and thicker, I remember I had several of these yellow ones, but I lost them.
https://www.ebay.pl/itm/372966718634


I think you're looking for part 3149c01 "Hinge plate 2 x 4":

It appeared in yellow in several sets during the 1970s.
Note that while this has solid plates (instead of plates with technic holes), it is as thick as the modern counterpart: 2 plates.

And to add: Very prone to braking so finding good ones second hand can be tricky. There is also a version with a 2x8 as the bottom plate and 2x4 for the top. Comes in the classic base colors: yellow, red, blue, grey, white and black. Yellow and red are most common, followed by grey. I have never seen a blue or black one but apparently they do exist.
